# How to get all orders id for curent customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, adminhtml, grid

I need to get all orders id for current customer in my custom customer tab!

I'm using: `$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();`

This is my Tab where I want to add Order N<sup>o</sup> and Sum:

[image]

Comment: you need put new question.. question was totally changed

Answer (score 3):

magento is stored `customer_email` in order table(`sales_flat_order`)

Now you can order `list of order by  using email id`  and but need fetch current customer email id then you can customer order list by below code:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$customerEmail)->addFieldToSelect('*');

foreach($orderCollection as $order){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($order->getData());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please user the below code.

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
```